# What should be SQL query for Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I do not have much experience with SQL.

I have table like,

```
DEST_NAME    DEST_ID      TAGS
India        Gen-1       XDHKGHDJD
USA          SPA         XLSDFASFG
India        HUS-1       XMAWOVMNF
India        Gen-1       XKILDKVMF
India        Gen-1       XPAWOVPOF
USA          SPA         VJSJGHSKL
```

I want,

```
DEST_NAME    DEST_ID      TAGS
India        Gen-1       XDHKGHDJD
India        Gen-1       XKILDKVMF
India        Gen-1       XPAWOVPOF
USA          SPA         XLSDFASFG
USA          SPA         VJSJGHSKL
India        HUS-1       XMAWOVMNF
```

Basically, I want records to group by according to its DEST_NAME and DEST_ID.

I tried using Group By, but for that I need to have one aggregate function in select statement. How can I do that ?

Comment: Please learn how to do some basic formatting, it makes your question a lot more understandable. Try out the icons in the toolbar above the text box. in particular {}

Comment: Yup, will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Try `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`

```
select DEST_NAME, DEST_ID, TAGS
from your_table
ORDER BY DEST_NAME, DEST_ID
```

But the sequence you display above does not make a lot of sense to me. I would expect this:

```
DEST_NAME    DEST_ID      TAGS
India        Gen-1       XDHKGHDJD
India        Gen-1       XKILDKVMF
India        Gen-1       XPAWOVPOF
India        HUS-1       XMAWOVMNF
USA          SPA         VJSJGHSKL
USA          SPA         XLSDFASFG
```

Comment: Sequence seem trivial at this time. I want this to be sorted. This helps ! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you. . .

```
 SELECT DEST_NAME, DEST_ID, TAGS
   FROM Table_Name
ORDER BY DEST_NAME, DEST_ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Use should use [ORDER BY](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13658.html) and you can use `ASC` or  `DESC` to display them ascending or descending order

```
SELECT DEST_NAME, 
       DEST_ID, 
       TAGS
FROM my_Table
ORDER BY DEST_NAME ASC, 
         DEST_ID ASC
```